# How to upload a file from Windows machine to Linux machine using command lines via PuTTy?

Tags: windows, linux, file-upload, command

I'm running Windows on my laptop at the moment and I want to upload files from my laptop to my uni's general purpose server, which runs both Linux and MacOSX.

So, I already opened up a connection to that server using PuTTy. But I failed to trying to upload a file from my laptop to that server using the commands guided in this website: http://news.metaparadigma.de/linux-upload-and-download-via-ssh-terminal-226/. Seems like it only works for Linux to Linux machine. It didn't recognize the Windows path that I entered (i.e. C:\a.txt).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try using SCP on Windows to transfer files, you can [download SCP from Putty's website](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). Then try running:

```
pscp.exe filename.extension username@domainname.com:directory/subdirectory
```

There is a full length [guide here](http://techie-buzz.com/tips-and-tricks/upload-files-to-linux-from-windows-using-pscp.html).

Comment: Don't worry about it, I don't freak out about accepting answers right away, also look into using it on Linux too as its a handy tool for moving files around via SSH.

Comment: Would it be better if we use a basic command like cp to move files around on Linux?

Comment: I mean between servers that are running Linux, not local to local.

Comment: The link to the guide has expired. Would appreciate if you could please update that.

Answer (score 4):

Pscp.exe is painfully slow.

Uploading files using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) is like 10 times faster.

So, to do that from command line, first you got to add the `winscp.com` file to your %PATH%. It's not a top-level domain, but an executable `.com` file, which is located in your WinSCP installation directory.

Then just issue a simple command and your file will be uploaded much faster putty ever could:

```
WinSCP.com /command "open sftp://username:password@example.com:22" "put your_large_file.zip /var/www/somedirectory/" "exit"
```

And make sure your check the synchronize folders feature, which is basically what `rsync` does, so you won't ever want to use pscp.exe again.

```
WinSCP.com /command "help synchronize"
```

Comment: Note: that trailing slash in `/var/www/somedirectory/` is important: without it SCP treats folder as file and tries to overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Put install directory path in environment values (PATH), and restart your PC if required.

Open cmd (command prompt) and type

```
C:/> pscp "C:\Users/gsjha/Desktop/example.txt" user@host:/home/
```

It'll be copied to the system.

Answer (score 0):

Better and quicker approach without any software to download.

- Open command prompt and follow steps mentioned below
- cd  path/from/where/file/istobe/copied
- ftp (serverip or name)
- It will ask for Server(AIX) User: (username)
- It will ask for password :   (password)
- cd path/where/file/istobe/copied
- pwd (to check current path)
- mput (directory name which is to be copied)

This should work.